# Form button not aligned in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, alignment

I'm making a search bar with a button next to it.

The button is perfectly aligned with the search bar on **Chrome** and **Opera**, but on **Firefox** the button goes up by a couple of pixels.

I've tried to play with the padding and the margin but it don't seems to work.

Here's my code and what it looks like on Chrome and Firefox :

**HTML :**

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<form id="gameSearch" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="game_search" maxlength="16" placeholder="Search...">
    <button class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

**CSS :**

```
button.icon {
    margin-left: -5px;
    background-color: #9b59b6;
    border: 0 none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button.icon:hover {
    background-color: #8e44ad;
}

input[type="text"] {
    border: 0 none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 50px;
    width: 350px;
    font: 25px sans-serif;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
}

form#gameSearch {
    padding: 50px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 430px;
}
```

What it looks like :

In Chrome

[image: In Chrome]

In FireFox

[image: In Firefox]

Comment: Have you enabled the box-sizing: border-box?

Comment: Yes, but no changes :( I've made a CodePen to try things [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwddxQ) if that help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to the input field:

```css
body {
background: #ddd;
}
   
button.icon {
box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-left: -5px;
    background-color: #9b59b6;
    border: 0 none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    width: 75px;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button.icon:hover {
    background-color: #8e44ad;
}

input[type="text"] {
box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 0 none;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 50px;
    width: 350px;
    font: 25px sans-serif;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

form#gameSearch {
    padding: 50px 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 430px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<form id="gameSearch" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="game_search" maxlength="16" placeholder="Search...">
    <button class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```